# Make the first option in a select element a selectable placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select element in HTML and I would like to give it a placeholder. I want this placeholder to be selectable (so no options are selected).

Because it is a placeholder I want the option text to be grey, and when the option is selected I want the select element's text to also be grey.

There are many questions that solve part of this problem, but none that offer a functional solution (that I can find).

Below is an example of the desired outcome (see the Campus dropdown).

[image: Example image.]

I am using React for the project, and have looked at the React-select package but cannot find a way to implement it like this.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a standard `<select>`, there's little styling of options available. You should be able to do it with widget libraries.

Comment: Why you don't use the dumb selection by making value =''  to the top option in the dropdown

Comment: @Barmar - These days you can mostly style `select` and `option` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS by making the option color grey with a selector, making the select grey when the default is selected, , and making other options a specific color (so they remain that color when the `select` is grey rather than inheriting grey from it). Here's an example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Example() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const onChange = ({currentTarget: {value}}) => {
        setValue(value);
    };
    return <select size="1" className={value ? "" : "greyed"} value={value} onChange={onChange}>
        <option value="">Default</option>
        <option value="A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B">Option B</option>
    </select>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
/*
We have this so that when the select is greyed, its options aren't
*/
select option[value] {
    color: black;
}

/*
Grey-out an element with the class, and option elements with blank values
*/
.greyed, select option[value=""] {
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```